# Why does libc++ not support class template argument deduction on multiset?

Tags: c++, templates, clang, c++17, libc++

```
#include <set>

int main()
{
    auto coll = std::multiset{ 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 7 };
}
```

The code above can be compiled by `vc++ 2019` and `g++ 9.0`, but cannot be compiled by `clang++ 8.0` as `clang++ -std=c++2a -stdlib=libc++ main.cpp`

**Why does libc++ not support class template argument deduction on multiset?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because it took until recently for [someone to implement it](https://reviews.llvm.org/D58582).

These features don't write themselves, and different projects prioritise different things.

You are of course free to join the project and contribute any features you feel are missing!

Comment: Can you clarify, this was a limitation of the multiset implementation, not of the compiler not respecting the standard? (my understanding, but could be clearer)

Comment: @Jeffrey Is there a substantive difference? This feature (in part) relies on deduction guides implemented in the standard library, and that simply hadn't been done until recently.

Answer (score 3):

This has been implemented for the upcoming clang 9 release.